# JOptionPane parsing arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

I am new to Java and arrays. I am trying to parse String input into int and into an array.
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
        public class OSL 
        {
                String[] ColorType = {"blue", "green", "white"};
                final int COLOURS = 3;    // tshirt colours choices
                int[] Color = new int[COLOURS];
                int order;

            public OSL()
            {  
                for (int index = 0; index < ColorType.length; index++)
                {
                    String orderItems = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of T-Shirts for " + ColorType[index]);
                    int items = Integer.parseInt(orderItems);
                }

                for (int index = 0; index < Color.length; index++)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ColorType[index] + ": " + Color[index]);
                }       
            }
                int orderItems;

        public int getorderItmes()
            {
                return orderItems;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
               new OSL();
            }   
        }
```

I can input the integer but it does not display them.

Comment: You never assign a value to any of the elements in `Color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you never apply the quanity for each color to the `Color` array in any way.  For example, you could do something like...

```
for (int index = 0; index < ColorType.length; index++)
{
    String orderItems = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of T-Shirts for " + ColorType[index]);
    int items = Integer.parseInt(orderItems);
    Color[index] = items;
}
```

Which simply applies the quantity that the user inputted to each element in the `Color` array